# ElectronJS: Change CSS style via Javascript and save it

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, electron

How can I please change the background color of a desktop application using `JavaScript` so that the settings are saved after the program is closed? I am using `ElectronJS` and since it is a desktop application, I cannot use cookies for this purpose.

[Application example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA60f.png)

What I've tried:

```
const color1Picker = document.getElementById("confirmColors")
color1Picker.onclick = () => {
  const color1 = document.getElementById("color1").value;
  const color2 = document.getElementById("color2").value;
  document.querySelector(":root").style.setProperty('--color1', color1);
}
```

Here I expected this solution to work only until the user exits the application.

What solution can I think of?

Somehow (probably using `NodeJS/Express`) save the variables from HTML into a JSON file and then reload them into Vanilla JS using `fetch`.

But this seems like too clumsy a solution to me.

Can you think of a better way please?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-settings

Comment: Thank you very much, however I do change the background color using CSS as it offers more options for editing styles. And if I understand correctly, at first glance this library does not affect the CSS file.

Comment: I use `electron-store` in my app to save user settings and other variables.  May want to take a look. https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store. You mentioned "save the variables from HTML into a JSON file and then reload them into Vanilla JS" and that's exactly what electron-store does.

Comment: Also, what prevents you from running `.setProperty(...)` upon application start with the value saved from the settings, either using `electron-settings` or `electron-store` as mentioned?

Comment: I think Express is a bit of an overkill just to implement this functionality. On first-run I would save a default `settings.json` file to the file system, which includes the default background color. Next, load the `settings.json` file (if not first run) and via IPC `window.webContents.send(...);`, update the application `<body style="background-color: #......;">` tag via Javascript. On UI color change, `send` the new color via IPC to the main process, update the `settings.json` file, then via the initial main to render IPC call, set the app `<body>` background-color again via Javascript.